# Configure a server to act as an internet gateway

Tags: linux, networking, centos, redhat, rocky-linux

I have two virtual servers hosted in Hetzner Cloud. The first server (let's call it Access Server) has a Public IP assigned and has internet access. The second server does not has a public IP assigned and cannot access the internet. Both server are part of the same private network with private IPs like `10.0.0.2` and `10.0.0.3`. I need to configure the first server (Access Server) to act as an internet gateway for the second server.
In the Access Server I have set `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` in the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file and masquerading is also enabled using `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-masquerade`.

But here's a few problems:

1. When no public IP is assigned, the VM created by the Hetzner Cloud does not show any network interface. For example if you run the `nmtui` there will be no network interface listed and no file is there in the `network-scripts` directory. The `ip link` command show two interfaces one is `lo` and the other one is `enp7s0`.
2. When I run the `ip route add default via 10.0.0.2` it shows invalid Gateway. I'm not sure if this is even the correct way to add a route.

The problem that I have is that I don't know how to create a Network Interface (for example what type of network, mac, etc.) whose Gateway I can set to the Access Server in the second server and I don't know what other things I should do in the Access Server to allow it to act as an internet gateway.

I cannot go with other solution such as creating a proxy server on Access Server as later this will cause a lot of problems (pods in k8s) and I guess installing a VPN like OpenVPN would be inefficient.

I would really really appreciate if someone provides me with some guidelines on how to do this as I could not find any usable resource over the internet. (ChatGPT could not answer it either)

Comment: @djdomi: Actually no. I have followed these but when I want to add the the Gateway using the `ip route add` command I get `Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.`, No resource is explaining that and how to fix it

Comment: please update the question, how you do what, its unclear what you have done, what research already you did etc, please read [ask]